# Robot Framework ImapLibrary Delete All Emails Not working

Tags: robotframework, imap

I'm using the **ImapLibrary Library** in Robot framework to read and verify the emails sent to the mailbox. I need to delete all the emails and keep my inbox clean for other tests. I used the **Delete All Emails** keyword in the library but it's not deleting any of the emails. The script looks like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ImapLibrary


*** Test Cases ***

Clear Emails
Open Mailbox    server=imap.googlemail.com   user=<MyEmail>    password=<****>
Delete All Emails
```

Can anyone tell me if I have done anything wrong?

PS: Email content verification is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-imaplibrary than you should first *select* emails using keyword `Wait For Email`.

If you are familiar with python you could check code and you will see that `Delete All Emails` works on `self._mails` variable which is populated by `Wait For Email`
[https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-imaplibrary/blob/master/src/ImapLibrary/**init**.py#L103](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-imaplibrary/blob/master/src/ImapLibrary/__init__.py#L103)

Comment: Yes, That was the case once I added wait for email and then delete, it worked. 
Thank you